# Как послать запрос с одной страницы на другую?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Я снова с глупым вопросом!

Значится так, я собираюсь сделать одну систему, скажем, работает она по принципу: пользователь тыркает на кнопку, и методом window.open открывается окно, а в этом окне происходят кое-какие действия, например, значения заносятся в БД или в сессию; потом это окно должно послать запрос на ту страницу, с которой он его открыл, команду, чтобы, к примеру, обновились данные на странице или, на худой конец, команду обновить страницу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно воплотить?  На юкоз сайтах, например, таким принципом сделана авторизация через соцсети!

Comment: http://nw.ucoz.com/ - вот здесь, при том я не говорю про всплывающее окно, я говорю про window.open, описанный здесь http://javascript.ru/window-open

Comment: Меня тоже интересует этот вопрос.
Для примера могу привести, Яндекс Спеллер ,который проверяет текст и в новом окне предлагает варианты исправления.
Вот тут можно посмотреть на это:
https://tech.yandex.ru/speller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью т.н. ajax механизма. Для этого используй класс XMLHttpRequest. В Интернете полно туториалов.

Comment: у меня там есть на страницы кнопки мэйлру вконтакте и фэйсбук - в зависимости от нажатой кнопки открывается windows.open и в этом окне происхдит авторизация по openapi и из этого окна должны вернуться данные о пользователе обратно как на этом сайте http://nw.ucoz.com/ так получится как думаете?

Comment: Хорошо, попробуем по-другому объяснить: тогда так "как window.open может вернуть параметры на страницу, с которого его открыли?"

Answer (score 1):

```
var w = window.open(null, null, "width=420,height=230");
w.document.write('<button onclick="window.opener.document.write(\'Ok\')">Send request</button>');
```